# Group window tabs on taskbar/panel

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I am using Linux Mint 18.2. I am wondering if there is a way to have multiple instance of the same program in the bottom panel have all their tabs stacked into one group that then expands when you click on it.

Essentially behave in an identical manner to windows tabbed applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Icing-Task-Manager](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/269). It works just like in Windows.